# Bug in CSS3 column layout when applied to pages loaded through jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a webApp (IOS only). I'm loading bits of HTML through jQuery and populate the app with them, adding them to the DOM.
I want to render one of those HTML bits with a CSS3 coloumn layout (in a .css file).
When the div with the column layout is loaded, I found that the links inside it are not working anymore. If I don't use the columns, they work normally.

Example of loaded HTML:

```
<div class='page layout_article'>
  <div class="articleColoumnLayout">
    <h2>Fragmentation in Care</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div class='quoteContainer'>
  <em>Lorem Ipsum</em>
  <a href='roz'>Roz</a> <!-- THIS IS THE NON WORKING LINK -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code that loads it (where #content is the div in which I load stuff):

```
var fileUrl = "path/page.html";
$.get(fileUrl, function(data){
  var html = $(data);
  var elements = html.filter('.page');
  var currentCell = 0;

  jQuery.each(elements, function(index, value){
    jQuery('<div/>', {
      id: "cell"+currentCell,
      "class": "cell"
      }).appendTo("#content");

  $('#cell'+currentCell).append(value);
  currentCell++;
  }
```

CSS

```
.articleColoumnLayout{
  margin: 64px;
  height: 608px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;

  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 32px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 32px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 32px;
}
```

Any pointer, suggestion, advice is more then welcome. I'm really close to give up on columns. 
Thanks a lot,

elena

--------------------------------------- # EDIT

I recreated the page I'm describing above and I can't reproduce the bug.
The cells divs that I'm creating with jQuery are contained within a Zynga Scroller
http://zynga.github.com/scroller/

that can be scrolled only along the X axis. I guess the bug has to do with the interaction between the Zynga scroller and CSS3 colomns.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var container = document.getElementById("container"); 
var content = document.getElementById("content");

// Initialize Scroller
scroller = new Scroller(render, {
scrollingY: false,
paging: true
});

// Setup Scroller
var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
scroller.setPosition(rect.left+container.clientLeft, rect.top+container.clientTop);
scroller.setDimensions(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight, 1024*pages.length, content.offsetHeight);
scroller.setSnapSize(1024, 738);
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any elements with transparent backgrounds positioned over the link that could be blocking it? It's an edge case but I've seen it happen.

Answer (score 0):

well I dont think this will work on ie6,ie7,ie8, you are better of using the float left instead or have a look at the link below.

http://dotmac.rationalmind.net/2011/03/cross-browser-multi-columns-with-jquery-and-css3/

this is cross browser aswell and most likely has had fixes etc...

Comment: I actually don't care about IE as this is going to be a web app for IOS only, but thanks anyway for the link! I added the info to the post, so it's clearer for others too.